# Javascript - Load page in frame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, frames

I use the following code to open a URL in the same tab:

```
<script>
function webD(){
webURL = document.webForm.webDirect.value; {
finalURL = "http://example.com/proxy/proxy.php/" + webURL;
}
location.href = finalURL;
}
</script>


<form name="webForm">

<input name="webDirect" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Send" onClick="webD()">
</form>
```

How can I make it open this URL in a frame with the id 'webfr'?

Comment: Please elaborate, are you using `iframe` or `frame`? Though both have `src` attribute/property, which contains the location for them.

Comment: @Teemu which is better for displaying a webpage??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the element by id. If you successfully found it, then you set its source.

```
function webD(){
webURL = document.webForm.webDirect.value; {
finalURL = "http://example.com/proxy/proxy.php/" + webURL;
}
var webFrame = document.getElementById("webfr");
if (!!webFrame) {
    webFrame.src = finalURL;
}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working.... Check the source code on http://rahul2001.com/proxy/

Comment: I fixed it... had to delete `location.href = finalURL;`. You should delete it from your answer...